# Echos showing before input is received

Tags: php, if-statement

I am new at PHP. Basically, I'm trying to make a simple if else statement that will let someone know if they are too young to see a rated R movie. The problem that I'm having is that what I want to output is shown way before I even get the input (age).

[image]

This is my current code:

```
<form action="movieProgram.php" method="post">
How old are you? <input type="text" name="age"/>
<input type="submit">
</form>



<?php 

/*if ($age < 17){ 
The $_POST['age'] retrieves data from the
form that is named age

*/
$age = $_POST["age"];
if ($age == ""){
    echo "";
}
elseif ($age < 17){
    echo "You are too young to watch the movie.";
}
else {
    echo "You are old enough to watch the movie.";
}
 ?>
```

How would I fix it? Any suggestions?

Comment: You can put a `name` attribute to your submit button then check if the form is submitted or not.

Comment: Your problem is when you first access the page `$_POST` is empty so `$age` will be `NULL` which will fail both your comparisons; hence your code outputs "You are old enough to watch the movie". You need to change the assignment of `$age` to stop that happening by checking that `$_POST['age']` is set before trying to use it e.g. `$age = isset($_POST['age']) ? $_POST['age'] : "";` or if you're using PHP7 `$age = $_POST['age'] ?? "";`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can put a `name` attribute to your submit button then check if the form is submitted or not.
Here is a demo what i have talked about

```
<form action="#" method="post">
How old are you? <input type="text" name="age"/>
<input type="submit" name="submit">
</form>



<?php 

/*if ($age < 17){ 
The $_POST['age'] retrieves data from the
form that is named age

*/
if(isset($_POST['submit'])) {
    $age = (int)$_POST["age"];
    if ($age == ""){
        echo "";
    }
    elseif ($age < 17){
        echo "You are too young to watch the movie.";
    }
    else {
        echo "You are old enough to watch the movie.";
    }
}

 ?>
```

Comment: Sifat Haque Thank you very much this worked as I wanted it to.